# Unable to format and install Windows

Tags: windows, linux, hard-drive, format

I am unable to format my hard disk and intall Windows XP. When I boot using Windows XP Professional CD ROM and do the setup, I end up in the below screen. I couldn't delete any partition and install Windows.

I have installed a Linux distribution previously, and it got corrupted. Now I am unable to install neither Linux nor Windows. I am using a Linux live USB flash drive to login and post this issue to the Internet. How can I fix this problem

[image: Disk partition boot menu]

Comment: What happens when you press enter or C?

Comment: Have you tried re-creating the partition table in linux?  Gparted provides a gui or just fdisk /dev/sdX then "o" will write a new partition table and then "w" to write it.  Just verify the fact that you're working on the correct hdd.

Comment: What happens when you press the <kbd>D</kbd> key on each of those partitions?

Comment: There is no C option in there.                                                             I have tried Gparted but it doesn't recognize the hard disks and list them. USB disk is the only being listed.                                                              If i click D, then windows says 'This partition cannot be deleted'

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the partition table is messed up. You should be able to open up [GParted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GParted) and delete all your partitions from your HDD using your live USB flash drive. Make sure you make the changes on your 80 GB drive and that you apply the changes when done. You will lose all your data on that drive, but it doesn't sound like you care about that.

Comment: I couldn't able to delete all partitions using Gparted

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: No errors. Gparted is just not listing the hard disks. It lists only the USB file system.

Comment: That's not a good sign, your disk is probably broken. To be sure Download UBCD and run a test on your disk. (Under HDD and then chose one that matches the brand of your HDD) If you have a newish computer, you should also be able to do a test of your Hard Drive through your BIOS. http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/download.html

Comment: Thanks for help. I am no master in working with hard disks. My computer is a older one, I will have to work my local service center to fix this. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Alright, just remember that if this "service center" is charging you, it might be cheaper to get a new Hard Drive, You can get a bigger one then you have right now for ~$50

Comment: Yeah, get a new hard drive. This one is toast if gparted can't see it.

Comment: Yeah, i would get a new Laptop instead of replacing my old PC.